# Creation of database history topic failed when submitting debezium task to confluent connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Trying to submit Debezium task to confluent throws following exception. Tried creating topic manually and then submit task, still getting same exception

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Creation of database history topic failed, please create the topic manually
at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.initializeStorage(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:349)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.intializeHistoryStorage(MySqlSchema.java:283)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlTaskContext.initializeHistoryStorage(MySqlTaskContext.java:192)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:126)
at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:45)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:157)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
```

Debezium version - 0.7.5
kafka - 0.10.0
confluent - 2.11

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Debezium uses Admin API not available in Kafka 0.10.0.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!